# Concrete5 ReMap Multilingual Pages

Tags: multilingual, concrete5

I'm using concrete5 Version 5.7.5.9 with Multilingual pages.

On System & Settings / Multilingual / Page Report

- the button for Re-Map and Un-Map are missing.

Instead it's written "Create the parent page first."
What does it mean? How can I solve the issue?

ps. please don't write "Create the parent page"... because they are existing

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The subpages, you have made plz check again. Might be the clone you have made is different.
example: You have to clone English to Another language 
         1. you are searching in **another pages** because of which it show you           "Create the parent page"
         2. So solution, Choose Source different n check it will show.